# Editing text file via awk command

Tags: awk, text-formatting, text

I am very newbie about on that command, so far I tried few things with that but I failed every time..

I have a text file (MWE) like below:

```
26 6 2020 09:06:23.300          277.430             50.131    20654.698008
26 6 2020 09:05:23.322          277.153             50.000    20493.667799
```

What I want to do with this text file? Let me explain that!

1. First of all, I want to re-arrange that file with respect to the **date/month/year/hour/minute/second** format. But all the other data related with the dates must be re-arranged again with respect to the dates. Is it possible to that via `awk` command?
2. Second of all, I want to arrange the text file to see an output like that given below (basically I want to change blank lines with ';' character):

```
26;6;2020;09;05;23;277.153;50.000;20493.667799
26;6;2020;09;06;23;277.430;50.131;20654.698008
```

It can be seen above also the timing delimiters has changed from ':' to ';' and **.timing** removed directly. Right now I am removing the split second via MS Excel (just copy+paste and edit). If there is also shorter way to do that I would love to learn!

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Comment: Here are some reasons why your question is being downvoted 1) Sample input is far lengthier than necessary to demonstrate your problem, it's not a MWE at all, 2) sample input has comment lines in the middle so we can't just copy/paste it to test with, 3) you didn't provide the expected output for your given sample input, 4) you didn't show any attempt to solve the problem yourself, 5) you didn't tell us what issues you've had trying to solve the problem that you need help with, just gave us a list of requirements for us to do the job for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to follow those rules. I am accepting all listed items from you except the MWE. I am working with 30k+ lines of text file. So from my point of view it is MWE. Well, I do not think you could be able satisfied with 3 lines of text file, right? I added only 2 lines to represent which text file starts where.. If it is problem I may erase them.

Comment: If 3 lines can demonstrate your problem as seems to be the case from what I understand from reading of your question then yes, 3 lines of input would be adequate. We certainly don't need to see any more than 10. Just figure out a **Minimal** Working Example. Some good rules of thumb are: a) if we need a scroll bar to see it, it's too much, and b) if it's so much input that you can't be bothered to create/post every line of the associated expected output then it's too much. It's useful to state the max size of your input file as that informs us on the types of solution that would work though.

Comment: With respect to `I am working with 30k+ lines of text file. So from my point of view it is MWE` - creating a smaller example than your real data doesn't mean you've created a **minimal** example. And to be a clear a MWE isn't just sample input, it includes the output you expect given that input. As well as helping us understand your needs, we need you to provide exact input we can test a potential solution against to get a simple pass/fail result if our program produces exactly the output you also provide.

Comment: Once we get pas the MWE part - the first 2 sentences in your first requirement aren't at all clear. 1) `I want to re-arrange that file with respect to the date/month/year/hour/minute/second format.` - your data is already sorted along those lines so what else is there to do? 2) `all the other data related with the dates must be re-arranged again with respect to the dates` - re-arranged in what order by what criteria applied to which fields? Please [edit] your question to clarify both of those sentences Having a good MWE that covers all your requirements will definitely help clarify that though

Comment: Also explain what `and .timing removed directly` means.

Comment: If any of the answers helped you then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Your question still isn't clear but it sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]+|:' -v OFS=';' '{sub(/\..*/,"",$6); print}' file |
    sort -nt';' -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 -k4,6
26;6;2020;09;05;23;277.153;50.000;20493.667799
26;6;2020;09;06;23;277.430;50.131;20654.698008
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the idiom to change the delimiters with awk:

```bsh
awk -F 'input_field_separator' -v OFS='output_field_separator' '{$1=$1; print}' file
```

The `$1=$1` bit forces awk to rewrite `$0` using OFS.

here, the input field separator is spaces or colon

```bsh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]+|:' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1; print}' file
```

Comment: Well, I did not expect to get an answer after I got "-2" votes in a minute for this question (I do not know why). Thank you!

Comment: Try not to take downvotes personally. Review https://unix.stackexchange.com/help -- perhaps a couple of people thought you could have done some more research

Comment: Thanks, I will do that! By the way (as I mentioned in my question at the first bullet), is  there any way to re-list (first date to last date) my text with respect to the colons 1,2,3,4 and 5?

Comment: The lack of a true MWE with expected output in your question is what leads people to post answers that don't do all of what you want because it's easy to miss requirements in text and  there's nothing to test a potential solution against. Also, accepting the first answer you get discourages anyone else from posting answers so then you may never find out if there are any better answers possible. When that first answer additionally doesn't do [all of] what you want then you're relying on the kindness of that one poster to help you further by enhancing their answer.

Comment: Lack of? If it was shorter, then it will be the perfect one? I am sorry about the other things (obviously new here), but about the MWE I am confused..

Comment: In this case, to demonstrate the question, probably you only needed one line of input and the expected output.

Comment: Glenn - the OP is asking for the output to be sorted too (`I want to re-arrange that file`) so they need to provide at least 2 lines of input.

Comment: @OnurGürdoğan the goal isn't to hack a bunch of lines out of your input to make it shorter. You could do that and the end result is already in an order that doesn't need to be sorted and so we can't use it for testing that part of your requirements. The goal is to provide minimal sample input and the exact output you need given that input such that the combination of both adequately test all of your needs - **that** is a MWE.

Comment: Okay now I could be able to sort my text file via `sort -k 1n -k 2n -k 3n -k 4n`

Comment: @OnurGürdoğan no, whatever kind of sorting you need that is not it for various reasons (e.g. it's not using the correct separator and isn't restricting the sort to just fields and is treating the month abbreviation as a number and it if treated it as alphabetical then the months would be out of order and it's sorting by day before month and month before year, etc.). Please just edit your question to provide a MWE so we can try to help you.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton but I have found my answer (I am working numerically so eventually I was going to change "Jun == 6" and "Jul == 7" etc.). I think I should have done more research before putting some phrases down here.. Anyway, for the sake of completeness I also edited the question if anyone wants to add answer, still...

Comment: I don't see any changes to your question, maybe you forgot to save them?

Comment: @EdMorton,done. I did not expect that much quick response, so please see the updated question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The expected output doesn't match your sample input (different dates, etc.), the 2 lines of sample input appear to already be in the desired date/time output order so they aren't a good choice to show/prove that sorting works, and it's still not at all clear what you mean by `all the other data related with the dates must be re-arranged again with respect to the dates.`

Comment: You should also add your attempt at solving the problem to your question. If you have a MWE with concise, testable sampe input and expected output plus show your attempt to solve the problem yourself and a clear statement of requirements then you definitely won't get downvotes and/or close votes as that's what's needed to ask a question on this forum. See [ask].

Comment: I updated your question so at least now your output values match your input values and your input is in a different order than is required for the output.